# Проектирование БД

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, проектирование, структуры

Вроде давно работаю с БД, но сейчас вошел в тупик. Есть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[learnerlist]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [name] NCHAR(10) NULL
)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[subject]
(
    [SubjectCode] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [SubjectName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь, необходимо ученику с `id=1`, т.е. `Иванову` поставить по русскому оценку 3 и сохранить в БД. Как это сделать? Необходимо добавить третью таблицу или как?

Конечно же хотелось бы соблюсти нормализацию. Но я также понимаю, что и "фанатеть" по этому поводу нельзя.

Comment: >Необходимо добавить третью таблицу или как?

разумеется. Ну или можете в таблицу учеников пихать поля с оценками по тому или иному предмету. Но это будет говнокодище

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Необходимо добавить промежуточную таблицу оценок [rating] состоящую из полей [Id], [LearnerId], [SubjectId], [Rating]
И правила нормализации будут соблюдены.